# What does @> mean in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, redash

Hi i have code that uses `@>` in a select statement. I need to change the query from redash counterpart to bigquery.

I have searched about the `@` that means the argument will be taken after in order to prevent it from sql injection.

```
select 
u.user_kvs IS NOT NULL AND u.user_kvs @> 'google_authenticator_enabled=>1'
from 
sometable
```

Not sure what it does. That's the question.

Comment: why is this tagged bigquery and postgresql? please remove ambiguity

Comment: Bigquery doesn't support dynamic sql so you will have to use your own code to replace the @ before submitting your sql. There is no concept of early/late binding.

Comment: @TamirKlein BigQuery supports https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries

Comment: Yes I know its still not the same concept of @ in sql as this is an api. However this can be part of the solution to the question although I have a feeling the question need some more details to be better answer.

Answer (score -1):

For parameterized queries in BigQuery,

> use the @ character followed by an identifier, such as @param_name.
>   [...] alternatively, use the placeholder value ?

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries.

For example:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT word, word_count
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
WHERE corpus = @corpus
AND word_count >= @min_word_count
ORDER BY word_count DESC;
```

You'll have to provide values for this parameters through the API at querying time.